# Mysql create index fails

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am trying to create an index on a mysql table as I have done it before. I am getting an error which says,

```
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "badetail" at position 20)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "docprofile" at position 30)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "USING" at position 42)
```

The sql is "CREATE INDEX trd ON badetail (docprofile)"

I am unable to find out the reason for these errors

Comment: How about `ALTER TABLE badetail ADD INDEX trd ( docprofile )` ?

Comment: Is the statement prior to the create index properly terminated? Can you post the full script so that we can see it all - Unrecognized statement type. (near "USING" at position 42) -no using statement appears in Create statement you have posted?